# IndexError in Python Function when iterating thru a split string with Range and Len methods

Tags: python, loops, range, index-error

**Problem Statement:** I am attempting to write a function that accepts a string and list.

- A string of words which I will use the `.split()` method to turning into a list
- make all words in list lowercase to make checking uniform
- iterate thru the list checking to see if the string list has words that are in the array.
- If they are it will remove the word
- join the list of non-filler words back into a string

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 55, in <module>
    no_filler = remove_filler_words(no_punction,filler_words);
  File "main.py", line 37, in remove_filler_words
    word_list[cap_word] = word_list[cap_word].lower()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code:

```
def remove_filler_words(cleaned_string:string, filler_words:list):
    cleaned_sentence = ""
    word_list = cleaned_string.split()
    for cap_word in range(len(word_list)):
        word_list[cap_word] = word_list[cap_word].lower()
        for filler_word in filler_words:
            if filler_word in word_list:
                word_list.remove(filler_word)
                line_join = " ".join(word_list)
                cleaned_sentence += line_join
   
 return cleaned_sentence
```

Replit: https://replit.com/join/dpxpwamhgy-terry-brooksjr

Comment: You loop over `word_list` (in the outermost `for` loop) but within the loop, you remove items from that same list.  That often causes problems in Python: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it for a similar problem and some tips.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
def remove_filler_words(cleaned_string, filler_words):
    word_list = cleaned_string.split()
    new_word_list = []
    for cap_word in range(len(word_list)):
        lower_word = word_list[cap_word].lower()
        new_word_list.append(lower_word)
        for filler_word in filler_words:
            if filler_word in new_word_list:
                new_word_list.remove(filler_word)
                cleaned_sentence = " ".join(new_word_list)

    return cleaned_sentence
```

I added all of the lowercase words, saved to `lower_word`, to a new list to account for the index error. Then, instead of having an empty list declared at the beginning, I assigned the `cleaned_sentence` variable to the join function which produces the expected result when returned.